# How do we calculate the rolling average of 2 months in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

Now, I am trying to calculate the rolling average over two months. I know that we can achieve this with the help of Quick Measure, but I need it without Quick Measure.

I am using the below expression:

```
Rolling Average Of 2 Month = 
VAR NumOfMonths = 12
VAR LastCurrentDate =
    MAX ( 'Orders [Order Date] )
VAR Period =
    DATESINPERIOD ( 'Orders [Order Date] , LastCurrentDate, NumOfMonths, MONTH )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
VALUES ( Orders[Order Date]). [Month]),
            Orders[Total Sales]
        ),
        Period
    )
RETURN
 Result
```

i got the wrong output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE39o.png)

Can anyone help me?

I need a solution each row, calculating the Rolling average

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Date/Calendar table?

Try:

```
Rolling Average Of 2 Month = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
      DISTINCT('Orders'[Order Date]),
      CALCULATE(SUM('Orders'[Total Sales]))
    ),
    DATESINPERIOD('Orders'[Order Date], MAX('Orders'[Order Date]), -2, MONTH)
  )
```